# How to render partial with django?

Tags: python, django, partial

I am working on a web project with Django and I have a list of objects displayed on the main column of my page. I want to make filters (like price filter, city...) of this objects on left. I would like to separate this two parts of code, with a special views method to render the left colum (filters) and an other one to render the central part.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `{% include %}` template tag.

Alternatively, you can create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) if the "partial" are used in multiple views and you don't want to explicitly insert extra context variables.